# Getting an Invalid Identifier Error when tying to JOIN a table with a NESTED subquery in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I get the following table as a result of NESTED subqueries:

| Structure_no | Name | Structure_type | Year Built | Description | Name_1 | Proximity | Route_no. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00011 | MainStreet | Bridge | 1961 | open | Clifton | ON | H20 |
| 00011 | MainStreet | Bridge | 1961 | open | Clifton | ON |  |
| 00029 | Gov_str | Bridge | 1972 | Transf. | Fraser | UNDER | H95 |
| 00029 | Gov_str | Bridge | 1972 | Transf. | Fraser | UNDER |  |
| 00069 | Cariboo | Bridge | 1997 | open | Creek | ON | P-002 |
| 00069 | Cariboo | Bridge | 1997 | open | Creek | ON |  |

The Oracle SQL query that I used to get the above table is:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT

        REGION, 
        ------
        ------
        CASE LAG_STRUC WHEN 0 THEN ROUTE_NUMBER END AS Route_Number
 
    FROM   
 (

     WITH remove_dupl AS 

       (

      SELECT * FROM
          (
             SELECT 

                a.STRUCTURE_ID,
                a.STRUCTURE_NO,
                a.NAME, 
                a.STRUCTURE_TYPE, 
                a.YEAR_BUILT,
                
                ---------- 
                ----------
                ----------
                
                FROM 
                
                APP_BIS.BIS_STRUCTURE a
                
                LEFT JOIN BIS_STRUCTURE_FEATURE_PROXMTY e ON a.STRUCTURE_ID = e.STRUCTURE_ID
                -------------
                -------------
                LEFT JOIN RIO_MIN_REG r ON (r.MIN_REG_ID = dis.MIN_REG_ID)      

           )
     )


SELECT  REGION, 
        DISTRICT, 
        --------
        --------
        -------- 
FROM remove_dupl WHERE rn=1 
    
   ) subQ2 
    
 ) subQ3_gps
```

The issue I face is that there is another table from the Database called GPS that I wish to join with this nested-subquery table.

That table is :

| Structure_no | Latitude | Longitude | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00011 | 191.8 | 276.8 | Start |
| 00011 | 194.6 | 278.5 | Mid |
| 00029 | 534.8 | 598.6 | SouthEnd |

I tried to join that table with that nested-subquery table using simple left join like:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
       SELECT
    
            REGION, 
            ------
            ------
            CASE LAG_STRUC WHEN 0 THEN ROUTE_NUMBER END AS Route_Number
     
        FROM   
     (
    
         WITH remove_dupl AS 
    
           (
    
          SELECT * FROM
              (
                 SELECT 
    
                    a.STRUCTURE_ID,
                    a.STRUCTURE_NO,
                    a.NAME, 
                    a.STRUCTURE_TYPE, 
                    a.YEAR_BUILT,
                    
                    ---------- 
                    ----------
                    ----------
                    
                    FROM 
                    
                    APP_BIS.BIS_STRUCTURE a
                    
                    LEFT JOIN BIS_STRUCTURE_FEATURE_PROXMTY e ON a.STRUCTURE_ID = e.STRUCTURE_ID
                    -------------
                    -------------
                    LEFT JOIN RIO_MIN_REG r ON (r.MIN_REG_ID = dis.MIN_REG_ID)      
    
               )
         )
    
    
    SELECT  REGION, 
            DISTRICT, 
            --------
            --------
            -------- 
    FROM remove_dupl WHERE rn=1 
        
       ) subQ2 
        
     ) subQ3_gps

    Left Join GPS ON subQ3_gps.Structure_no = GPS.structure_no
```

But I get invalid identifier error.

Can anyone please assist me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting the `left join`.  Does `subQ_gps3` select the `structure_no`?  Is `subQ_gps3` in scope wherever you are putting the `left join`?

Comment: My apologies.. I have entered the full code that I am trying in order to get the result... The left joining of the GPS table is right at the end of my query...

Comment: Does `subQ_gps3` select the `structure_no`?

Comment: Yes sir!.. It does..

Comment: What identifier does the error refer to?  You probably need to post a reproducible test case (something that we can run locally that reproduces the problem.  Ideally something that removes any complexity that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue.